# PHP - Replacing column's value from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have to tables. (I'm using `MySQL`). They have the same number of columns. Let me show you by showing some of it:

Table: `payment`

```
Id   TransactionCode   InvoiceNumber   
1     238694               322
2     518675               325
6     348611               401
13    750329               412
```

Table: `payment2`

```
Id   TransactionCode   CustomerId
1     238694               32
2     NULL                 36
13    79                   48
```

So, table `payment` is the one holding the correct values and as you see, the two tables are almost the same, I just need to move all the data from `payment.TransactionCode` and replace with `payment2.TransactionCode`.

I want to update table payment2 as this:

```
    Id   TransactionCode   CustomerId
    1     238694               322
    2     518675               325
    6     348611               401
    13    750329               412
```

For selecting that, I used this:

```
SELECT payment.Id AS id, 
       payment.TransactionCode AS TranC , 
       payment2.TransactionCode AS TranC2
        FROM payment
            LEFT JOIN payment2
                ON payment.Id = payment2.Id
```

It works perfectly fine. But how do I `update`/`set` the values it?! I tried this but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE payment 
        SET payment.TransactionCode = (SELECT payment2.TansactionCode 
            FROM payment2 
                WHERE payment.TransactionCode<>payment2.TransactionCode 
                    AND payment.Id=payment2.Id)
```

Comment: Seems fine but you've issued a `SELECT` clause instead of an `UPDATE` one (make sure to backup!), plus you forgot to close the parenthesis at the end.

Comment: thanks for the early reply
Forgetting a parenthesis was my fault when I wrote it here with no textEditor. It's free of such flaws in my actual code. I edit it anyway for others.
Thanks mate

Comment: Hey @Sean, Sorry Buddy.. Now I Saw Your Comment there .. let me try this..

Comment: you want data from payment2 to come and sit in payment table ?

Comment: No man, table: payment is complete one, this time I want the data from payment come and sit in payment2.  ONLY the TransactionColumn are different, so that is just enough to be changed. ;)

Comment: one last question.. only those value will come whose id matches.. Is it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88823/discussion-between-danish-enam-and-sean).

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the tables on your `UPDATE` clause like this:

```
UPDATE payment
JOIN payment2 ON (payment.Id=payment2.Id) AND
             ((payment.TransactionCode<>payment2.TransactionCode) OR
              (payment.TransactionCode IS NULL) AND (payment2.TransactionCode IS NOT NULL) OR
              (payment.TransactionCode IS NOT NULL) AND (payment2.TransactionCode IS NULL))
SET payment.TransactionCode = payment2.TransactionCode
```

Comment: Tried it, got this error: 
    Unknown column 'payment2.TansactionCode' in 'field list'

Comment: It didn't yield any error but it didn't affect anything neither. This is what I received:
Statement affected 0 row(s) in 7.00 milliseconds.

Comment: Note that I've edited the answer to reflect NULL value differences.

Comment: I'm starting to be worried man!
again I received this: Statement affected 0 row(s) in 68.00 milliseconds.

Comment: Check your tables contents again. I've tried the same values as you've written above and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: I used the SELECT code that I wrote in the question after I used your code. It is supposed to show everything the same as it is in table payment but they still are different. just like before.